# Zoom background image only

Tags: html, css

I want to zoom the background image only

```css
.prod_img:hover {
  webkit-transform: scale(1.04);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.04);
  -o-transform: scale(1.04);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.04);
  transform: scale(1.04);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.prod_img {
  content: ' ';
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  height: 580px;
  width: 300px;
}

.protransparentbg {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
}
```

```html
<<div id="prod_main">
  <div id="product_content">

    <li class="prod_img prod_img1" id="prod_img1" style="background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/beautiful_landscape_picture_02_hd_pictures_166284.jpg);background-size: cover;background-position: center center;">
      <div class="protransparentbg">
        <h4 class="">FIBER FLOOR MAT</h4>
      </div>
    </li>



  </div>
  </div>
```

this is my code but in this zoom effect works for the background image and also it effect the content in the image.how to give the effect only to the background image.

Comment: Just take into consideration that if you put that h4 in the div that has an animation applied to it, it would animate too, even if its position is absolute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to change in css part and use `pesudo elements` to get it

Remove `background-image` in html part and use it in css `pesudo element`

```css
.prod_img {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  height: 580px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.prod_img:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/beautiful_landscape_picture_02_hd_pictures_166284.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  "

}

.protransparentbg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, .8);
}

.prod_img:hover:before {
  webkit-transform: scale(1.04);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.04);
  -o-transform: scale(1.04);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.04);
  transform: scale(1.04);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="prod_main">
  <div id="product_content">
    <li class="prod_img prod_img1" id="prod_img1">
      <div class="protransparentbg">
        <h4 class="">FIBER FLOOR MAT</h4>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```